# Redirect to anchor and add a style class to the ID

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a newsfeed where users can comment on posts.
When someone shares a comment and another users clicks on the shared link, he is redirected to that comment with the help of anchor-tags/id. All no problem, but I would like to highlight the comment by adding a colored border. How can I add another class to the comment when reaching given comment?

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{path: '/postId', hash: '#commentId'}">Redirect</nuxt-link>

<div :id="commentId" class="comment">
  {{ comment }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to this route `https://localhost:3000/test#commentId` with this kind of code

```html
<template>
  <div :id="commentId"
    class="comment"
    :class="{ 'focused-comment-styling': $route.hash === '#commentId' }"
  >
    Teal-colored if matching the hash
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.focused-comment-styling {
  color: hsl(195, 100%, 60%);
}
</style>
```

will indeed apply the `focused-comment-styling` class to the element.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you will need to set up a watcher on the `$route` parameter, I haven't tested this exact code, but something along these lines should work:

```js
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    document.getElementById(to.hash).classList.add("focused-comment-styling");
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to use ```to.hash.substring(1)``` to remove the ```#```. Now, it works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Prefer to not use query selectors tho.

Comment: @kissu If I use only **to.hash** i get `Cannot read property 'classList' of null` because If I console.log(to.hash), I get the commentId with # `#611a44ebf8d88c27e296060f`. How should I handle it?